# Copy a URL from a post to a custom field in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using IFTTT.com to import youtube videos into Wordpress. One of the elements I am importing is the URL of the youtube video. I would like to copy this url to a custom field that my theme comes with to display embedded video. I realize that I can import the embedded video from IFTTT to my post but I prefer the formatting that my theme provides when using the video embed custom fields they created.

Example:

URL imported to post looks like this:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qCVQpcY1au4
(example taken from IFTTT I hope the video selection doesn't annoy too much)

I need to copy this to VideoEmbedCustomField like this:
http://www.youtube.com/embed/qCVQpcY1au4

I unfortunately do not have code to work from. I was looking into plugins that update posts. Any help or advice is appreciated.

1. Import video from YouTube to a Wordpress post using IFTTT.com. This works.
2. On import, I need a function that can recognize the URL imported to the post

   ```
   example:  <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/qCVQpcY1au4" id="youtubelink" class="ytlink">YouTube Link</a>
   ```
3. If the url exists it will transform the link to

   ```
   http://www.youtube.com/embed/qCVQpcY1au4
   ```

   and insert it in the custom field

Comment: So what you need to do is transform your first url (with v=blah) to the second (/embed/blah)?

Comment: Right, I need to transform the urls. The first url is in the post body. I can add a class or ID to it. I need a way to copy and transform and write this url in the post to a custom field. This would preferably happen when importing the post from YouTube via "If This Then That".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you need a function in an appropriate place to do this conversion via regex:

```
public static function convertYouTube($original) {
    $pattern =  '/http:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([\w]+)/';
    $replacement = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/${1}';
    return $embedLink = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$original);
}
```

The `pattern` dictates what part of the input you want to capture. In this case it's the `([\w]+)` clause, roughly translating to "grab the sequence of one or more alphanumeric characters" that happen to come after your (properly escaped) constant youtube url.

[`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) is a php function that will allow you to take the part you grabbed and replace the rest. Now that you have a properly converted url you can drop it into whatever field you need.